# Mapped type produces error when source type has properties of differing primitive types

Tags: typescript

I have the following type that removes `readonly` modifiers from properties and read-only arrays:

```
type Mutable<T> = {
    -readonly [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends ReadonlyArray<infer U> ? U[] : T[P];
};

class ClassWithReadOnlyProperties {
    readonly FirstName!: string;
    readonly LastName!: string;
    readonly MiddleNames!: readonly string[];

    dothing() {
        let mutable = this as Mutable<ClassWithReadOnlyProperties>;  // Works
        mutable.MiddleNames[0] = "someValue";                        // Works
    }
}
```

The above code works. Adding a new `number` property:

```
class AnotherClassWithReadOnlyProperties {
    readonly FirstName!: string;
    readonly LastName!: string;
    readonly MiddleNames!: readonly string[];
    readonly Age!: number;

    dothing() {
        let mutable = this as Mutable<AnotherClassWithReadOnlyProperties>; // Error
        mutable.MiddleNames[0] = "someValue";
    }
}
```

causes this error:

> Conversion of type 'this' to type 'Mutable' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.
> Type 'AnotherClassWithReadOnlyProperties' is not comparable to type 'Mutable'.
> Types of property 'MiddleNames' are incompatible.
> The type 'readonly string[]' is 'readonly' and cannot be assigned to the mutable type 'string[]'.(2352)

Adding any non-primitive property works fine, as does making all properties the same primitive type - only adding a new primitive of a different type to the other primitives on the class seems to cause the error. The type of the array seems to be immaterial.

This is in TypeScript 3.6.3 and above - the same code causes no errors in TypeScript 3.5.1.

Why is this happening?

Comment: If your question is "why is this happening" it could very well be a compiler bug (I think the inconsistent behavior is actually the fact that it allows the first example, because even adding no properties will cause the error if you rewrite the type manually; see [here](https://tsplay.dev/Wyvaxw)).  If your question is "how do I deal with this" then you should just write `this as unknown as Mutable<AnotherClassWithReadOnlyProperties>` as the error suggests.  If either or both of those are your question I'm happy to write up an answer.  If not, please clarify by asking an explicit question.

Comment: I haven't found an obviously applicable GitHub issue about this; if someone wants [to file one](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=Bug_report.md&title=), they might find [this code example](https://tsplay.dev/W44E7W) to be useful.

Comment: Thanks for the input - I've clarified the question. I think your code example shows the inconsistent behaviour nicely, and I'd rather not plaster over that by converting to `unknown`.